# getSupportFragmentManager(); instance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using 3 classes to reuse how the fragments should be placed in the screen. The First class is generic abstract class that are used to add the fragment to the transaction. The other two classes are extending the abstract class with an implementation for the fragment.

The First Class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

2nd Class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class CrimeActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeFragment();
    }
}
```

3rd Class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity{
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new CrimeListFragment();
    }
}
```

With the above, does i am using the same reference of getSupportFragmentManager(); that was already defined in the abstract generic class, or each one of the 2nd and 3rd Class get their own references. How Java really works here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I using the same reference of `getSupportFragmentManager();`?

Yes, that is how class inheritance works in Java. `FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager()` is the same method in all your classes.